# Call recording for Galaxy S2 with kitkat ROM

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.4-kitkat, call-recording

I'm looking for a call recording app \ mod that works on Galaxy S2 with android 4.4 ROM.

I used several apps with previous versions (mainly on stock ROM's) but none of the apps I tried worked on KitKat ROM

Currently I use [Resurrection Remix ROM](http://www.resurrectionremix.com/) but I don't mind changing to a different ROM (I understand that CM based ROMs don't have call recording support)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to go for [Call Recorder - ACR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nll.acr&hl=fr), it works fine with my CM11